# How to determine one program output to pipe as next program input in shell using ${PIPESTATUS[*]}

Tags: bash, shell, pipe

I am new to shell script. I have a scenario where i need to get the exit status of one shell script and pass its value as input(if exit code is zero/otherwise exit the main shell script file) to the next shell script and continue until it executes all the scripts. Below is the code i tried.but its not working as expected.

```
status=`run1.sh`
if [[ status -eq 0 ]]; then
status=`run2.sh`
else
exit 1
fi
if [[ status -eq 0 ]];then
status=`run3.sh`
else
exit 2
fi
```

Its running successfully for first 2 scripts. It's failing on second if block, even though the output value of run2.sh is 0. I searched in google, its suggesting to use {PIPESTATUS[@]}, I tried it by replacing exit 1 with pipestatus and pass pipestatus in the second if block like below.

```
status=`run1.sh`
if [[ status -eq 0 ]]; then
status=`run2.sh`
else
exit ${PIPESTATUS[1]} ## pipestatus[1]- is run2.sh output value
fi
if [[ ${PIPESTATUS[1]} -eq 0 ]];then
status=`run3.sh`
else
exit 2
fi
```

I think i am not clear on how to use pipestatus. I would appreciate if anyone can provide me some example to my scenario.

Comment: Have you tried using `set -e` in the beginning f the script?

Comment: The return value from the deprecated "backticks" you are using is not the same as PIPESTATUS.  Backticks (you should use `$(...)` instead) return the standard output stream, not the exit code.

Answer (score 1):

`status` is a static string; you are not examining the variable you created at all.

There is no pipe here so `PIPESTATUS` does not come into play. It's for code like

```
one | two
```

where traditionally the exit status of `one` wasn't available to the shell; Bash changed that by exposing results from every process in a pipeline.

Having your scripts print the number zero to signal success is not how it's usually done. A command produces both output and a status code (the number you give as the argument to `exit`, or in a function, to `return`), and code would usually examine the latter. It is exposed in `$?` but the shell's control structures implicitly check it under the hood, so your code would look like

```
if run1.sh; then
    if run2.sh; then
        if run3.sh; then
            ...
```

provided you change them to produce a useful exit code. Though this could be further simplified to

```
run1.sh || exit
run2.sh || exit
run3.sh || exit
```

or even to

```
set -e
run1.sh
run2.sh
run3.sh
```

Comment: Or `run1.sh && run2.sh && run3.sh`

Comment: sorry for the late reply. set -e worked for me. thank you.